# Custom Grid with Radio button extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want a custom grid, which contains a radio at the beginning of the column. Only one of the row in the grid can be selected ( that too by selecting the radio ).

I used the following approach to achieve the above said,

```
renderer:functiom(val){
return Ext.String.format("<input type='radio' name='rowSel' value={0} />",val);
}
```

Unlike Extjs radio, this is a html radio, which lacks richness, similarly i can't show validation error messages.

Is there a possibility to achieve the above using extjs radio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever seen the grid examples in sencha doc [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html), you will find it use `Ext.selection.CheckBoxModel` to add a new checkbox column as first grid column (for multi-select grid).

Because Sencha does not provide a `RadioModel` (maybe it is not necessary because the normal grid has the same functionalities), I think you should write a new SelectionModel class which extends the `Ext.selection.RowModel` to meet your needs. You can reference the way in `Ext.selection.CheckBoxModel` and `Ext.selection.RowModel`

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize the Ext JS 3.4 CheckboxGrid (Single Select)  to RadioGrid.

Please refer: [Customized Radio Grid in Ext JS 3.4](http://non-stop-ext.blogspot.in/)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem too. 
So I used singe mode from `Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel` like this.

```
{
                    margin: '10 0 0 0',
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    minHeight: 100,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    frame: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    itemId: 'previewGrid',
                    selModel: selModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                        singleSelect : true
                    })
....
```